# codeigniter view are not loading in constructor with parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter, openx

I am trying to load a view from constructor with parameter $data. Earlier it was working fine and now suddenly it stopped working. Below is the code:

### permissionerror View

```
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="6" align="left" valign="top" background="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/topbg.gif"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/top-left.gif" width="5" height="34" /></td>
                <td height="34" align="left" valign="middle" background="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/topbg.gif" class="heading">Access Forbidden</td>
                <td width="6" align="right" valign="top" background="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/topbg.gif"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/top-right.gif" width="5" height="34" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top" background="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/main-content-bg-left.gif">&nbsp;</td>
                <td height="165" valign="top"  bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="leftredheading"><div style="margin:30px auto;padding-left:15px"><? if(isset($sn_error)) echo $sn_error;?></div></td>
                <td align="right" valign="top" background="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/main-content-bg-right.gif">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="bottom" background="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/bottom-bg.gif"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/bottom-left-corner.gif" width="5" height="5" /></td>
                <td valign="top" background="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/bottom-bg.gif"></td>
                <td align="right" valign="bottom" background="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/bottom-bg.gif"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/bottom-right-corner.gif" width="5" height="5" /></td>
              </tr>
            </table>

Template code:

<?php $this->load->view('includes/login/header'); ?>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#e7e7de">
  <tr>
    <td width="18"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/zero.gif" width="18" height="1" /></td>
    <td width="191"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/zero.gif" width="191" height="1" /></td>
    <td width="18"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/zero.gif" width="18" height="1" /></td>
    <td width="100%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="161"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/zero.gif" width="18" height="1" /></td>
    <td width="191"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/zero.gif" width="191" height="1" /></td>
    <td width="18"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/zero.gif" width="18" height="1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><table width="191" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td background="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/left-menu-white-bg.gif"> <?php $this->load->view('includes/login/top_right'); ?> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="50" background="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/left-menu-white-bg.gif">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td background="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/left-menu-white-bg.gif"><table width="166" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/needhelp-top.gif" width="166" height="7" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#F8F7EC"> <?php $this->load->view('includes/login/bottom_right'); ?>
                <br /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#F8F7EC"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/needhelp-bottom.gif" width="166" height="7" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
          <br /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td background="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/left-menu-white-bg.gif"><table width="191" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td height="6" align="left" valign="top"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/left-bttom.gif" width="6" height="6" /></td>
            <td width="100%" background="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/leftbottom.gif"></td>
            <td height="6" align="right" valign="top"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/bg/right-bttom.gif" width="6" height="6" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
         <br /></td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td valign="top"  <? if($main_content != 'dashboard' || $main_content == 'publisher_dashboard') { ?> colspan="3" <? } ?>><?php $this->load->view($main_content); ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <? if($main_content == 'dashboard' || $main_content == 'publisher_dashboard') { ?>
    <td align="right" valign="top"> <?php $this->load->view('includes/login/left'); ?>
    </td>
    <? } ?>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php $this->load->view('includes/login/footer'); ?>
```

Here in the above code i am checking whether logged in user is having permission for access then do else part otherwise through the error from if case block.

In IF case it loads the error template.

Please somebody help me to fix the above issue ASAP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `parent::__construct()`, not `parent::Controller()`.

Edit:

After it was made clear that CodeIgniter 1.7.1 is used and after the view itself was shown, this is your issue:

Your view tries to echo `$error` instead of `$sn_error`. If you don't pass `$data` to the view, then `$sn_error` (which is checked for) isn't set and that error doesn't occur - that's why the view gets loaded in that case.

Comment: My constructor is loading perfectly. I have problem in my if block. The statement "view load" is not working with parameter $data. In case i remove $data it loads the view perfectly. Please advice

Comment: If your constructor runs fine that way, it means that you're using a pretty old version of CodeIgniter, for which I can't really give you an advice.

Comment: That's 9 versions behind the current one, you really should consider upgrading.